# clojure how to stop and output while in a recursive loop

Tags: loops, recursion, clojure

So I am making a A* search for an 8 puzzle and it seems to work, but the problem is that once it finds the solution it keeps going through a priority map and outputting all the possibilities. Is there a way to just stop and output once I meet a condition?

*NOTE*: i feel like making the doseqs lazy with a for loop and making them not eval the whole thing would be best. is there a way to do this?

here is my code:

```
(defn a-star

   ([board history]

     (if (at-end? board) (print-board board)


           (let [options (filter #(possible-move? % board) *moves*)
                move (into (pm/priority-map) (for [move options] [move (global-man-dis (move-tile board move))]))]


              (doseq [pair move :let [next-move (key pair)]] 


                  (print-board (move-tile board next-move))
                  (println)
                  (a-star (move-tile board next-move) next-move (conj history board))

              )
          )
    ))



  ([board prev-move history]

     (if (or (at-end? board) (history-check history board)) (print-board board)


      (let [options (get-queue board (dont-go-back prev-move))
            move (into (pm/priority-map) (for [move options] [move (global-man-dis (move-tile board move))]))]

        (doseq [pair move :let [next-move (key pair)]] 


             (print-board (move-tile board next-move))
             (println)
             (a-star (move-tile board next-move) next-move (conj history board))

         )
       )
     )))



(defn -main [& args]
  (println "insert a list all numbers no spaces or letters")
  (def board (mapv (fn [^Character c] (Character/digit c 10)) (read-line)))
  ;(def testt [0 8 4 7 2 1 3 5 6])
  ;(def testt [1 2 3 5 4 6 8 0 7])
  (a-star board [])
  )
```

Comment: Just a thought, since this is clojure you could call the algorithm by its original name, a*, instead of a-star.

Comment: While the `(def board ...)` statement in `-main` works, it would be better to use a `(let [board ...] ...)` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon my comment from yesterday, here's a full generic A* implementation in Clojure. Since you didn't include the various helper functions your `a-star` function is calling in your question, I don't know how exactly you've transformed the 8 puzzle problem into a graph search problem, but you should be able to adapt the following code yourself.

```
(ns a-star.core
  (:require [clojure.data.priority-map :refer [priority-map]]))

(defn pred->path
  "Determine the path to GOAL from the map of predecessors PRED."
  [pred goal]
  (loop [node goal, path ()]
    (if (contains? pred node)
      (recur (pred node) (cons node path))
      (cons node path))))

(defn expand
  [node h [open g pred] succ cost]
  (let [g-succ (+ (g node) cost)]
    (if (and (contains? open succ)
             (>= g-succ (g succ)))
      [open g pred]
      [(assoc open succ (+ g-succ (h succ)))
       (assoc g succ g-succ)
       (assoc pred succ node)])))

(defn a*
  "Determine the shortest path from START to GOAL in graph GRAPH
with heuristic cost function H. GRAPH format is {from {to cost}}."
  [start goal graph h]
  (loop [open (priority-map start 0)
         closed ()
         g {start 0}
         pred {}]
    (if (empty? open)
      :no-path-found
      (let [node (key (peek open))]
        (if (= node goal)
          [:path-found (pred->path pred goal) (g goal)]
          (let [successors (apply dissoc (graph node) closed)
                [open* g* pred*] (reduce-kv (partial expand node h)
                                            [(pop open) g pred]
                                            successors)]
            (recur open* (conj closed node) g* pred*)))))))
```

The test code should clarify how to use the `a*` function:

```
(ns a-star.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [a-star.core :refer :all]))

(deftest test-a*
  (is (= (a* :sb :wb
             {:sb {:kl 70, :kr 145}
              :kl {:ff 103, :lh 53}
              :ff {:wb 116}
              :lh {:wb 183}
              :kr {:hb 84}
              :hb {:wb 102}}
             {:sb 222, :kl 158, :ff 96, :wb 0, :lh 108, :kr 140, :hb 87})
         [:path-found '(:sb :kl :ff :wb) 289])
      "Find path in a directed graph.")
  (is (= (a* :sb :wb
             {:sb {:kl 70, :kr 145}
              :kl {:sb 70, :ff 103, :lh 53}
              :ff {:kl 103, :wb 116}
              :lh {:kl 53, :wb 183}
              :kr {:sb 145, :hb 84}
              :hb {:kr 84, :wb 102}
              :wb {:ff 116, :lh 183, :hb 102}}
             {:sb 222, :kl 158, :ff 96, :wb 0, :lh 108, :kr 140, :hb 87})
         [:path-found '(:sb :kl :ff :wb) 289])
      "Find path in an undirected graph.")
  (is (= (a* :sb :wb
             {:kl {:sb 70}
              :ff {:kl 103}
              :lh {:kl 53}
              :kr {:sb 145}
              :hb {:kr 84}
              :wb {:ff 116, :lh 183, :hb 102}}
             {:sb 222, :kl 158, :ff 96, :wb 0, :lh 108, :kr 140, :hb 87})
         :no-path-found)
      "Find no path in reversed directed graph."))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! sorry I did not reply sooner but i did start taking your advice the other day and its working better. this code also helps me understand to.

Answer (score 1):

One common way is to put an `if` statement around the recursive call at the end. Something like:

```
(if-not (finished? move)
   (a-star ... ))
```

ps: one insignificant point of formatting, some clojure programmers find it easier to read if all the consecutive closing `)`'s go on the same line, though this is purely personal taste.

Comment: hmm interesting but in the search when i find my goal and i start going back wont the doseqs continue again (since the finished? would only apply to one functions)? also I tried recur in place of a-star and it does not seem to like that. "assert failed" can't recur frame"

Comment: I think a* is probably not worth the trouble to convert to tail recursion, because of the branching nature of the algorithm. +1 for the suggestion of putting closing parens on the same line as the prior statement. Most of us who do lisp know non-lisps too, and it is easier to get into "lisp mode" of reading if you use conventional lisp formatting.

Comment: hmm i was thinking that I can change the doseqs back into for loops to make them lazy and have a condition to make them not evaluate the sequence when i dont want them to.  but i dont know how to do that

Comment: I removed my comment about tail recursion, I was just plain wrong.

Comment: @user2150839: I think this is a good place to tell you that the confusion about the mixed behaviour of `doseq`s and recursion is an indicator towards the fact that your A* implementation is wrong. In a true A* implementation, you use a single priority queue that gets updated during every iteration. You do not iterate over a constant priority queue and then recurse into and backtrack from other instances of the function that will iterate over their own constant queue. A good Clojure implementation of A* would be a tail-recursive function that primarily passes on an updated version of the queue.